# Definite integrals and area

Tags: definite-integrals, area

Consider the function $$f(x)=\int_{-3}^{x}t\cdot dt.$$
Formula wise, this translates to $$f(0) = \frac{0^2}{2}-\frac{(-3)^2}{2} = -4.5.$$
How do we derive this graphically? The absolute value of the area obtained is the same. But what are the rules to be applied for determining sign?

[image: Graph of y=x]

Comment: "what are the rules to be applied for determining the sign?" Do you mean why is it $-4.5$ as opposed to $4.5$? This is because the definite integral measures the area underneath the graph to the $x$-axis. So when the graph is below the $x$-axis, we get negative area.

Comment: Also, I do believe you mean $(-3)^2$ and not $-3^2$ in your calculation (big difference; $18$ to be exact).

Comment: There is a big difference when calculating the VALUE of a definite integral and calculating the AREA of a region. Areas of regions must be positive, so it is necessary to take the absolute value of the integral. To calculate areas which have intersected the line $y=0$, it must be split up into several regions and be calculated from there.

Comment: I took the liberty to correct "$-3^2$" for the OP.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I actually wanted to understand the role of upper and lower limits as well when computing the integral.

Comment: Thanks @zipirovich for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the integral as a Riemann sum.  (The integral is a limit of Riemann sums, so we can pick one of the ones that go by as we take the limit and talk about that one.  Our argument applies to each and every one of them, so pick a generic one.)  That Riemann sum has a partition of the independent variable.  For $f(0)$, the integral is over the interval $[-3,0]$ and the sum has a partition for that interval:
$$  -3 = x_0 <x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_{n-1} < x_n = 0  \text{.}  $$
Think about the Riemann sum for your integral.
$$  \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^* (x_i - x_{i-1})  $$
is the sum of *signed* areas of rectangles of width $\Delta x_i = x_i - x_{i-1}$ and height $x_i^*$, where $x_i$ is some point in the $i^\text{th}$ piece of the partition, $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$.  (Generically, in the integral $\int_a^b g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$, the height is $g(x_i^*)$, but your integral has $g(t) = t$, so $g(x_i^*) = x_i^*$.)  (Typical recipes for choosing the $x_i^*$ include: always pick the lower bound of the partition piece, $x_{i-1}$, (called a left sum), the upper bound, $x_i$, (called a right sum), the middle $\frac{1}{2}(x_{i-1} + x_i)$, (called a middle sum), and there are other recipes for choosing a point in each piece of the partition to feed to $g$ to get the height of the rectangle.)

Since $x_{i-1} < x_i$, every $\Delta x_i$ is positive.  If $x_i^*$ is positive, the *signed* area of the rectangle is positive.  If $x_i^*$ is negative, the *signed* area of the rectangle is negative.  Now sum these rectangles.

For your $f(0)$, all of the $x_i^*$ are in the interval $[-3,0]$.  Since the height of the function in your integrand is negative over that entire interval, the signed areas of the rectangles in the Riemann sum are all negative, so the Riemann sum is negative.  This happens for *all* the Riemann sums in the limit giving us the integral.  As we take the limit, these sums approach $-4.5$, which is the value of $f(0) = \int_{-3}^0 \; x \,\mathrm{d}x$.

So we have the signed area of this triangle.  The area (which is unsigned) is $4.5$.  **Only** because the integrand, $x$, has a fixed sign is this the absolute value of the signed area.  If the integrand is positive throughout an interval or negative throughout an interval, the area is the absolute value of the signed area.  If the integrand changes sign, there is cancellation of signed area -- the area between the function in the integrand and the $x$-axis is then larger than the absolute value of the signed area.

Consider $f(1)$.  The integral gets negative signed areas for $x_i^*$ in $[-3,0]$ and positive signed areas for $x_i^*$ in $[0,1]$.  So some of the signed area cancels.  In fact, the signed area of the triangle over $[0,1]$ exactly cancels the signed area of the triangle over $[-1,0]$, so $f(1) = -4$.  But the area between the graph of $g(t) = t$ and the $t$-axis over the interval $[-3,1]$ is $4.5 + 0.5 = 5$, where the "$4.5$" is the area of the triangle over (well, "under", but ths is the usual way to say it) $[-3,0]$ and the "$0.5$" is the area of the triangle over $[0,0.5]$.

If you are seeking a generic rule, break your interval of integration into pieces so that the integrand has the same sign throughout each piece (i.e., everywhere in the first piece the integrand has the same sign, everywhere in the second piece the integrand has the same sign, ..., but we allow the sign to be positive in some pieces and negative in the others).  The area between the graph of the integrand and the independent variable axis is then the sum of the absolute values of the signed areas (integrals) over each piece.

There is a slightly different but equivalent way to say this.  To get the area, we really just want to replace each negative signed area in a Riemann sum with a positive signed area, so that we just sum up positive areas to get the total (unsigned) area.  Since the signs come from the integrand, we can take the absolute value of the integrand to make this happen.  So the integral to get the area is 
$$  \hat{f}(x) = \int_{-3}^x \; |t| \,\mathrm{d}t  \text{.}  $$
Now, this is a bit of a cheat.  Since we do not have an elementary integration rule for absolute values, we end up breaking the interval of integration into pieces where the function in the absolute value brackets has constant sign (just like we described in the previous paragraph) so that, in each piece, we can replace $|g(x)|$ with $g(x)$ (if $g$ was positive in that piece) or with $-g(x)$ (if $g$ was negative in that piece).  So really, we end up doing the same thing, we just arrive at the same result by different routes.

Also, you've been a little uncareful in your notation.  When you write $\frac{-3^2}{2} = \frac{-9}{2}$, you actually mean $\frac{(-3)^2}{2} = \frac{9}{2}$, which is a very different thing.

Comment: Thanks Eric. That resolved my doubt. And, that was a little careless on my part.